# How Scenarios work in behave BDD test

Tags: python, bdd

I want to know the Scenarios in a feature execute one by one  or randomly??

Feature: feature name

Scenario: scenario1
      Given some condition
       When some action is taken
       Then some result is expected.

Scenario: scenario2
      Given some other condition
       When some action is taken
       Then some other result is expected.

Scenario: scenario3
      Given some other condition
       When some action is taken
       Then some other result is expected.

Is  scenario2 execute after the scenario1 ?  And the scenario3 will be execute after the scenario2.

thx,

Answer (score 0):

The order of Scenarios should be exactly as in the file, except that cases when some custom sorting is using. But to be more accurate we need to know what is a testing framework you are using, because each of them has a lot of different parameters for running the tests. But by default it should be exactly in the file.